# PHP and Imagick error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob 'test.pdf'-

Tags: php, windows, xampp, imagick

I am having a hard time using Imagick in PHP 7.3 to convert PDF to image. When I run the following code:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readimage('test.pdf');
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob 'test.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3315 in C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php(40): Imagick->readImage('test.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php on line 40
```

I tried using an absolute path (C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\test.pdf) but I got the error below:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readimage('C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\test.pdf'); 

Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php(41): Imagick->readImage('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\pdf_to_img.php on line 41
```

I followed this [guideline][1] to select the Imagick library and my settings are:
-Windows 10
-XAMPP
-PHP 7.3.27 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2021 20:46:26) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
-Thread Safety => enabled
-Architecture => x64

Any solution would be appreciated. Thnx

UPDATE: Found the solution: changed the address by escaping some of the slashes. Instead of:

```
$im->readimage('C:\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\test.pdf');
```

Wrote:

```
$im->readimage("C:\\xampp\htdocs\My codes\cURLs\php-curl-class\PDFs\\test.pdf");
```

Comment: Do you have ghostscript installed in your computer?

Comment: I did. But it didn't help so I removed it.